# How to use knex alertableBuilder to update column comment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

The migration file is below:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';
exports.up = async (knex: Knex): Promise<any> => {
  await knex.schema.raw(`
  COMMENT on "USER".user_invite_state is '0 - not sent invitation email, 1 - sent without acknowledged, 2 - sent with acknowledged, 3 - invite failed';
  `);
};
exports.down = async (knex: Knex): Promise<any> => {};
```

When i do knex migration, i got the error as below:
migration failed with error: 
  COMMENT on "USER".user_invite_state is '0 - not sent invitation email, 1 - sent without acknowledged, 2 - sent with acknowledged, 3 - invite failed';
   - syntax error at or near "COMMENT on "
error: syntax error at or near "COMMENT on "

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: When i run the sql on pgAdmin, it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with the queryBuilder, it whole purpose it to bridge between different db syntaxes.

```js
export async function up(knex: Knex) {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tn, t => {
    t.integer('colName')
      .comment('this is my comment')
      .alter();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Boggles be how they go through the effort of implementing features while not adding it to the documentation for anyone using it to see. Is there code coverage for documentation? xD